# Creating dynamic links for a HTML email with embedded ruby

Tags: html, ruby, email, ruby-on-rails-4, hyperlink

I have a simple question about links in HTML emails

I am trying to add a simple dynamic link in an HTML email to my site like this

```
     <a href="https://www.example.com/microposts/<%=@micropost.id %>/responses/<%= @response.id %>/notification">MySite</a>
```

This fails, but this works

```
   <a href="https://www.example.com">MySite</a>
```

I am assuming its to do with the embedded ruby but strangely, the links work if I view them on my iphone.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me....

I needed to construct the link using the ActionMailer generating URLs instructions, see here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#generating-urls-in-action-mailer-views

My URL is

```
   <%= link_to "View response", notification_micropost_response_url(@micropost, @response) %>
```

The default host must be first set in the dev and prod environment config files:

Example (development.rb)

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```